# parse XML 1.1 control characters with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, character-encoding, elementtree

In Python, I'm parsing XML containing a control character:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.fromstring('<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?><field>foo &#11; bar</field>')
print(tree.text)
```

Control characters are allowed by XML 1.1, but the parsing fails.
Is there something I'm missing, or does xml.etree.ElementTree not support such control characters?

Answer (score 1):

The ElementTree parser on linux at least, uses the system's expat parser.  The libexpat maintainers [do not plan to support](https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/issues/378) XML 1.1.

The lxml package, which provides a similar API to ElementTree uses `libxml2` to parse XML.    The libxml2 maintainers [also do not plan to implement](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2010-July/msg00017.html) XML 1.1 (this reference is quite old, but the libxml2 [homepage](http://xmlsoft.org/) only references the 1.0 standard.

You need to find

1. a parser that actually implements XML 1.1
2. Python bindings for the parser.

Answer (score 0):

@snakecharmerb is right. Recommend you a more tolerant library, maybe you will like it.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?><field>foo &#11; bar</field>'
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print(doc.field.text)
```

Result:

```
foo &#11; bar
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/blob/master/doc_examples